# Should I check-in iOS xcuserdata?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, git

Should I be checking the following files in `git`?

```
# On branch 4-menu
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   myapp-ios.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/harith.xcuserdatad/
#   myapp-ios.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/harith.xcuserdatad/
```

I am new to `iOS` programming and curious if I need to ignore them

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952491/is-it-safe-to-ignore-xcuserdata-with-git-if-using-launch-arguments and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478/git-ignore-file-for-xcode-projects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those files contain your user data and workspace settings of your Xcode projects including the file/folder orders, etc. seen on the left pane in your Xcode, and the usual habit is to avoid committing them into the repository.

See the .gitignore file [here](https://gist.github.com/adamgit/3786883).