# Xcode 11.2.1 Crashes When Opening a Project

Tags: ios, xcode

I just downloaded Xcode 11.2.1 and now, when I try to open one of my existing projects, Xcode immediately crashes.   This happens on just one of my projects but not on others.  I can create a new blank project.  All of these are iOS "SingleView" projects with SwifUI.

Has anyone else seen this?

Here is the start of the crash log:

```
Process:               Xcode [17611]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               11.2.1 (15526.1)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-15526001000000000~4 (11B500)
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       833502318
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [17611]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-11-13 13:56:16.523 -0500
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.1 (19B88)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        59421F89-0AB5-B6E2-B437-53D2CEC68F51


Time Awake Since Boot: 170000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 11B500
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): Cannot update for observer <NSColorPanel 0x7fabf38331a0> for the key path "_keyWindow.firstResponder" from <IDEApplication 0x7fac53511310>, most likely because the value for the key "_keyWindow" has changed without an appropriate KVO notification being sent. Check the KVO-compliance of the IDEApplication class.
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: 

Backtrace:
  0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1   DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3   -[NSKeyValueNestedProperty object:withObservance:didChangeValueForKeyOrKeys:recurse:forwardingValues:] (in Foundation)
  4   NSKeyValueDidChange.llvm.18255262684423441536 (in Foundation)
  5   NSKeyValueDidChangeWithPerThreadPendingNotifications.llvm.18255262684423441536 (in Foundation)
  6   -[NSApplication _setKeyWindow:] (in AppKit)
  7   -[NSWindow _changeKeyAndMainLimitedOK:] (in AppKit)
  8   -[NSWindow _makeKeyRegardlessOfVisibility] (in AppKit)
  9   -[NSWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:] (in AppKit)
 10   -[NSWindow(NSWindow_Theme) _prepareToRestoreRegularFromDock:forceActivation:wantsToBeKey:] (in AppKit)
 11   -[NSWindow(NSWindow_Theme) _prepareToRestoreFromDock:forceActivation:wantsToBeKey:] (in AppKit)
 12   -[NSWindow(NSWindow_Theme) _doRestoreComingFromDock:forceActivation:wantsToBeKey:] (in AppKit)
 13   -[NSWindowStackController handleDeminimizingWindow:] (in AppKit)
 14   -[NSWindow(NSWindowTabbing) _prepareTabbedWindowDeminimize] (in AppKit)
 15   -[NSWindow(NSWindow_Theme) _prepareToRestoreFromDock:forceActivation:wantsToBeKey:] (in AppKit)
 16   -[NSWindow(NSWindow_Theme) _doRestoreComingFromDock:forceActivation:wantsToBeKey:] (in AppKit)
 17   -[NSWindow _reallyDoOrderWindowAboveOrBelow:relativeTo:findKey:forCounter:force:isModal:] (in AppKit)
 18   -[NSWindow _reallyDoOrderWindow:relativeTo:findKey:forCounter:force:isModal:] (in AppKit)
 19   -[NSWindow _doOrderWindow:relativeTo:findKey:forCounter:force:isModal:] (in AppKit)
 20   -[NSWindow orderWindow:relativeTo:] (in AppKit)
 21   -[NSWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:] (in AppKit)
 22   __103-[NSWindowStackController _doTabSelectionAndWindowOrderingAtIndex:makeKeyAndOrderFront:justOrderFront:]_block_invoke (in AppKit)
 23   NSPerformVisuallyAtomicChange (in AppKit)
 24   -[NSWindowStackController _doTabSelectionAndWindowOrderingAtIndex:makeKeyAndOrderFront:justOrderFront:] (in AppKit)
 25   -[NSWindowStackController setSelectedWindow:] (in AppKit)
 26   -[NSWindow(NSWindowTabbing) _doTabbedWindowOrderFront] (in AppKit)
 27   -[NSApplication _setKeyWindow:] (in AppKit)
 28   -[NSWindow _changeKeyAndMainLimitedOK:] (in AppKit)
 29   -[NSWindow _makeKeyRegardlessOfVisibility] (in AppKit)
 30   -[NSWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:] (in AppKit)
 31   -[NSWindowController showWindow:] (in AppKit)
 32   -[IDEWorkspaceDocument setOrderedWindowControllerNames:] (in IDEKit)
 33   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKeys:count:maybeOldValuesDict:maybeNewValuesDict:usingBlock:] (in Foundation)
 34   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:key:key:usingBlock:] (in Foundation)
 35   _NSSetObjectValueAndNotify (in Foundation)
 36   -[IDEWorkspaceDocument revertStateWithDictionary:] (in IDEKit)
 37   -[DVTStateToken _pullStateFromDictionary:] (in DVTFoundation)
 38   -[DVTStateToken pullStateFromRepository] (in DVTFoundation)
 39   -[IDEWorkspaceDocument _readFromURL:ofType:simpleFilesFocused:error:] (in IDEKit)
 40   -[IDEWorkspaceDocument readFromURL:ofType:error:] (in IDEKit)
 41   -[NSDocument _initWithContentsOfURL:ofType:error:] (in AppKit)
 42   -[NSDocument initWithContentsOfURL:ofType:error:] (in AppKit)
 43   -[IDEDocumentController makeDocumentWithContentsOfURL:ofType:error:] (in IDEKit)
 44   __97-[NSDocumentController makeDocumentWithContentsOfURL:alternateContents:ofType:completionHandler:]_block_invoke (in AppKit)
 45   -[NSDocumentController makeDocumentWithContentsOfURL:alternateContents:ofType:completionHandler:] (in AppKit)
 46   __80-[NSDocumentController openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:display:completionHandler:]_block_invoke (in AppKit)
 47   __145-[IDEDocumentController _coordinateReadingAndGetAlternateContentsForOpeningDocumentAtURL:resolvingSymlinks:thenContinueOnMainThreadWithAccessor:]_block_invoke (in IDEKit)
 48   __144-[NSDocumentController _coordinateReadingAndGetAlternateContentsForOpeningDocumentAtURL:resolvingSymlinks:thenContinueOnMainThreadWithAccessor:]_block_invoke_4 (in AppKit)
 49   __144-[NSDocumentController _coordinateReadingAndGetAlternateContentsForOpeningDocumentAtURL:resolvingSymlinks:thenContinueOnMainThreadWithAccessor:]_block_invoke_2.872 (in AppKit)
 50   __144-[NSDocumentController _coordinateReadingAndGetAlternateContentsForOpeningDocumentAtURL:resolvingSymlinks:thenContinueOnMainThreadWithAccessor:]_block_invoke.871 (in AppKit)
 51   __144-[NSDocumentController _coordinateReadingAndGetAlternateContentsForOpeningDocumentAtURL:resolvingSymlinks:thenContinueOnMainThreadWithAccessor:]_block_invoke.869 (in AppKit)
 52   ___NSMainRunLoopPerformBlockInModes_block_invoke (in AppKit)
 53   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ (in CoreFoundation)
 54   __CFRunLoopDoBlocks (in CoreFoundation)
 55   __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 56   CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 57   RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 58   ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 59   _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
 60   _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 61   -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 62   -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 63   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 64   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 65   main (in Xcode)
 66   start (in libdyld.dylib)

abort() called
```

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13600567/77567) help?

Answer (score 22):

Open project folder
show package contents from .xcworkspace or .xcodeproj
You will see 2 folders **xcshareddata** and **xcuserdata**
Please remove **xcuserdata** folder
Try to open application

Comment: That worked.   I removed ../project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata and all is good now. Thanks!

Comment: Worked !! You just saved my time. Can you please explain why this issue is coming?

Comment: After updating to Version 11.3 (11C29) I keep getting ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-15712/IDEKit/Workspace/IDEWorkspaceDocument.m:3435
I went on to "Show package contents" of the ".xcworkspace" workspace directory and deleted "xcuserdata" folder. This resolved the crash for me.
link - https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123204
link - https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/117363

Answer (score 13):

Please perform the following:

1. **Open the project's folder**
2. **Right-click on the file named** `.xcworkspace`
3. **Click on** `Show package contents`
4. **Delete the folder named** - `xcuserdata`

   - It is safe to remove the `xcuserdata` folder - this folder contains some user preferences for the specific project ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952491/is-it-safe-to-ignore-xcuserdata-with-git-if-using-launch-arguments)).

You can read more about the solution above [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123204). See *udoy.soumik*'s response.

Comment: These instructions can also be found in [this old stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13600567/77567).