# Xcode Error Report Xcode quit unexpectedly

Tags: xcode

After updating Xcode to 11.2.1 I am unable to open my project. Everytime I try to open it Xcode crashes and I get the following error.

```
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 11B500
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-15526.1/IDEKit/Workspace/IDEWorkspaceDocument.m:3429
Details:  selection failed. window:<IDEWorkspaceWindow: 0x7f95c63dfb70> currentlySelectedTabbedWindow:<IDEWorkspaceWindow: 0x7f95c7c51350>
Object:   <IDEWorkspaceDocument: 0x7f95c60d7580>
Method:   -_restoreSelectedTabsByIdentifierFromStateSaving:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f95c0703790>{number = 1, name = main}
```

Comment: Hi Andre, please see my answer and let me know if it helped - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58844184/xcode-11-2-1-crashes-when-opening-a-project/58844362#58844362

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems that **Xcode** cannot restore the tabs / files you have opened the last time see `Method:    -_restoreSelectedTabsByIdentifierFromStateSaving:`.

The latest ui state including opened files, curent target etc. is stored in the `UserInterfaceState.xcusertate`. You can find the file in your Xcode project folder under:

```
/<your_project_path>/<your_project_name>.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/<username>.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
```

Just remove the file e.g. via `rm` and **Xcode** shall work again.

Comment: I've spent all day trying to find a solution and this fixed it! I'm absolutely over the moon. Thank you!

I'm curious, how are you so familiar with the internals of Xcode?

Comment: From a terminal window typing the following is an easy way remove the offending file from all your projects: find . -name "UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate" -exec rm {} \;

Comment: Thank you! I have tried to delete whole folder but then also it was not working bt after follow this, this works well, But can you explain why this happen nd also why this happen only for specific project because all other projects are working well ?

Comment: It did not work when I removed `xcuserdata`, but I did the clean project's clone and replaced `ios/theftpatrol.xcworkspace` in my broken project and I could open the project! Your steps helped me a lot, thank you!

Comment: I am confused. My *. xcodeproj is not a directory, but you are listing it like it is a path...

Comment: @ScottF, it's a file. Either you access the directory content via the terminal or you can open the directory (in Finder) by right click on the file icon > Show Package Contents.

Answer (score 5):

*Open project folder show package contents from .**xcworkspace** or .**xcodeproj** You will see 2 folders **xcshareddata** and **xcuserdata** Please remove **xcuserdata** folder Try to open application*
**Xcode** will work properly